# A problem to find a countable set with an uncountable family of subsets.

Tags: real-analysis

Show that there is a countable set $X$ that contains an uncountable family $Y$of subsets that if the sets $W,Z \in Y$ and $Z \cap W  \neq \varnothing $ then $W \subset Z$ or $Z \subset W$

I think that if I had two real numbers I could find two sequencies of rational numbers which converged to them and they might have some common numbers but these sequencies dont contain each other . Any ideas please ?

Comment: Hint, I would look at subsets of the natural numbers. That's the original "countable set". Most of the elements of $Y$ will have to be infinite since there are only countably many finite subsets.

Comment: @EthanBolker Really? Did looking at subsets of $\mathbb N$ help you to find a solution? Looking at subsets of $\mathbb Q$ there's an obvious one: all sets of the form $\mathbb Q\cap(-\infty,a)$ where $a\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: @bof I did not actually answer the question using my hint. I just wrote out what I would have tried first. Your elegant solution might or might not have come to me in time. I think you should post it as an answer.

Comment: @bofThank you for your idea.if i an right you tell me to take Y=Q∩(−∞,a) that is a uncountable family, X=Q and the only think i have to prove is that   W⊂Z or Z⊂W?Am i right,tell me please.

Comment: the fact that Y=Q∩(−∞,a) that is a uncountable family has to be proved or i can say that
R.is uncountable so Y is uncountable.?if there is something else to be proved i would be gratefyll for an complete answer if you could give to me.Thanks!